# PayPal IPN item option and selection reporting syntax for cart and single transactions

Tags: paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I want to parse item option_name and option_selection values from both single and cart transactions.  The IPN and PDT Variables documentation is not clear on how this is reported - or if it is reported - for the 7 options possible for each item in the transaction.  The documentation states (for option_name):

> Option 1 name as requested by you. PayPal appends the number of the
>   item where x represents the number of the shopping cart detail item
>   (e.g., option_name1, option_name2).

The item index variable X is missing from this description.  In any case, the index needs to be 2-dimensional for a cart (item#, option#) and 1-dimensional for a single transaction (option#).  The documentation implies that option_name and option_selection are active only for cart transactions, but this seems wrong.

Can anyone clarify for me what the correct reporting syntax is for these two transaction types?  I'm about to set up a sandbox test to find out experimentally in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what language you're working with, but here's a PHP snippet of how to parse the item details for PayPal standard orders.

```
$i = 1;
$cart_items = array();   
while(isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]))   
{   
    $item_number = isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_number' . $i] : '';   
    $item_name = isset($_POST['item_name' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_name' . $i] : '';   
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity' . $i]) ? $_POST['quantity' . $i] : '';  
    $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_handling = isset($_POST['mc_handling' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_handling' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_shipping = isset($_POST['mc_shipping' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_shipping' . $i] : 0;
    $custom = isset($_POST['custom' . $i]) ? $_POST['custom' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name1 = isset($_POST['option_name1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection1 = isset($_POST['option_selection1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name2 = isset($_POST['option_name2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name2_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection2 = isset($_POST['option_selection2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection2_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name3 = isset($_POST['option_name3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name3_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection3 = isset($_POST['option_selection3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection3_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name4 = isset($_POST['option_name4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name4_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection4 = isset($_POST['option_selection4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection4_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name5 = isset($_POST['option_name5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name5_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection5 = isset($_POST['option_selection5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection5_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name6 = isset($_POST['option_name6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name6_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection6 = isset($_POST['option_selection6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection6_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name7 = isset($_POST['option_name7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name7_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection7 = isset($_POST['option_selection7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection7_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name8 = isset($_POST['option_name8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name8_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection8 = isset($_POST['option_selection8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection8_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name9 = isset($_POST['option_name9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name9_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection9 = isset($_POST['option_selection9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection9_' . $i] : '';

    $btn_id = isset($_POST['btn_id' . $i]) ? $_POST['btn_id' . $i] : '';

    $current_item = array(   
                           'item_number' => $item_number,   
                           'item_name' => $item_name,   
                           'quantity' => $quantity, 
                           'mc_gross' => $mc_gross, 
                           'mc_handling' => $mc_handling, 
                           'mc_shipping' => $mc_shipping, 
                           'custom' => $custom,   
                           'option_name1' => $option_name1,   
                           'option_selection1' => $option_selection1,   
                           'option_name2' => $option_name2,   
                           'option_selection2' => $option_selection2, 
                           'option_name3' => $option_name3, 
                           'option_selection3' => $option_selection3, 
                           'option_name4' => $option_name4, 
                           'option_selection4' => $option_selection4, 
                           'option_name5' => $option_name5, 
                           'option_selection5' => $option_selection5, 
                           'option_name6' => $option_name6, 
                           'option_selection6' => $option_selection6, 
                           'option_name7' => $option_name7, 
                           'option_selection7' => $option_selection7, 
                           'option_name8' => $option_name8, 
                           'option_selection8' => $option_selection8, 
                           'option_name9' => $option_name9, 
                           'option_selection9' => $option_selection9, 
                           'btn_id' => $btn_id
                          );   

    array_push($cart_items, $current_item);   
    $i++;   
}
```

You would end up with an array, $cart_items, that you could easily loop through to process the items whether there was only a single item or multiple items from a cart.

The snippet was pulled from my (rather old but still very useful) [PayPal PHP IPN Template](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn-php-template/).

Comment: Thanks, Andrew - I did see your code in my initial search but didn't quite understand it.  I'm using a Salesforce APEX handler.
From this code I glean that the syntax for optioned cart items is:
option_nameN_X and option_selectionN_X where
X is the item number and N is the option number (0-6, if IPN variables use the same syntax as the onN and osN HTML variable equivalents).
This implies that optioned single item transactions are:
option_nameN and option_selectionN
Is this right?
Thanks again.

Comment: Note: by single and cart transaction I am distinguishing between web_accept(Buy Now, Donate Now) and cart(Add To Cart) button types. A cart can of course have a single item, but for my application it is common to use an optioned single donation transaction (_donate vs. _xclick).

Comment: OK! I studied your full PHP code, and everything I'm curious about is there. Only one question remains: is the option number N range 0-6, or 1-7?  PayPal allows only 7 options per item, but HTML variables range from 0-6.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the "why?" things you'll find in PayPal sometimes.  In this case they use 0 - 6 in your HTML but then in IPN they use 1 - 7.

Comment: Good ol' PayPal. Comprehensive yet incomplete, highly structured yet incoherent.  Thank you for your help.